# Scope zsh history to current file tree if a file exists

Tags: zsh, command-history

I would like to have the following behavior for zsh history:

1. If the current directory has a `.zsh_history` file, then treat that file as the history
2. If the current directory does not have a `.zsh_history`, start going up the tree until you find one (similar to how git looks for `.git`)
3. If you've reached the filesystem root without finding a `.zsh_history`, use the regular, system-wide history file

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Looking at other questions, I see some methods for always scoping the history to the current directory. However, I don't want to do this - generally I want to keep using the system-wide history file. I only want to scope to current directory *occasionally*, for those locations which comprise a proper context (such as some git repos), which I want to indicate by creating a file in that directory. This file should apply to child directories as well.